# Array of random numbers optimization

Tags: javascript

I have a function that generates an array of random numbers. It works, but I feel that it might works slow on big numbers. Is there a way how to optimize it?

```js
function renerateRandomNumbers(maxNumber, randomNumbersCount) {
    let i;
    const arrResult = [];
    for (i = 0; i < randomNumbersCount; i++) {
        let rand = Math.random() * (maxNumber);
        rand = Math.round(rand);
        if (arrResult.indexOf(rand) === -1 ) {
            arrResult.push(rand);
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arrResult;
}
```

Comment: Your current algorithm is `O(n^2)`, the most efficient solution would be one in `O(n)` - check out my answer below for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - To any future users, @ScottSauyet's solution should be the accepted answer. It is a more consistently efficient solution than mine.

I think the most algorithmically efficient way to solve this would be to generate the list of all possible numbers from `0-maxNumber`, shuffle that array (`O(n)`), and then take the first `randomNumbersCount` numbers from the shuffled array. It would look like the following:

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
}

function generateRandomNumbers(maxNumber, randomNumbersCount) {
  var possibleNumbers = [];
  // populate array with all possible values
  for (var i = 0; i <= maxNumber; i++) { possibleNumbers.push(i); }
  // shuffle the array to get a random order of the possible numbers O(n)
  shuffleArray(possibleNumbers);
  // trim the array down to only the first n numbers where n = randomNumbersCount
  possibleNumbers.length = randomNumbersCount;
  return possibleNumbers;
}

console.log (generateRandomNumbers(10, 5));
console.log (generateRandomNumbers(10, 5));
console.log (generateRandomNumbers(10, 5));
```

Comment: Your solution looks good. I'm not using `splice` anymore in my answer. It looks like both of our answers have `O(n)` complexity, isn't it?

Comment: @qiAlex Yeah, I believe with your latest edit it makes your code `O(n)`

Comment: I believe that it was even without last edit. I guess that `array.splice(-1, 1)` will not reindex whole array. Most likely it just will remove the last element

Comment: @qiAlex Yeah, tbh I'm not sure. I think you are probably right on that. `.pop()` would do the same thing with less keystrokes, and I know that for sure is `O(1)`

Comment: Igree, `.pop()` looks better than `.splice(-1, 1)`. Simple question from a first point of view, but tricky if dig deeper

Comment: @qiAlex No kidding!

Comment: @qiAlex I made some edits to my answer: Populate with `for` loop to populate with `Number`s instead of `String`s and only use 1 array the entire time. Extremely time & space efficient now. Total # of iterations = 2n. Total # of arrays = 1.

Comment: For performance, you're comparing apples to oranges.  The solution from @qiAlex also adds a `sort` at the end -- noting that it might be optional.  If you remove that, they have very similar timings.

Comment: There are also likely improvements to this.  There is no reason to shuffle the whole array when we only want some fixed subset of them.  We should be able to stop the `shuffle` loop after `count` interations, and just take the `count`-length tail from the result.

Comment: @ScottSauyet True, I forgot to take out the sort. The results are about the same, though. As for not shuffling the entire array, I kind of see your point, although I'm not sure how that would work for a maxNumber of 1000000 and count of 5. Stopping after swapping 5 random indexes is *hardly* "random"

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code is that complexity grows geometrically because it have a chance generate number that was already picked multiple times.

What we need to achieve is to get number on every iteration to achieve iterations count to be equal to the `randomNumbersCount`.

How to avoid multiple same random numbers?

let's say you want to have **5** random numbers from **0-10** range

**First iteration**

1. Create an array with values `var candidates = [0,1...10]`
2. Generate random number let's say `0`
3. Store the number `candidates[0]` in results
4. Remove `0` from `candidates`. To avaoid reindexing of the `candidates` array we will put `candidates[candidates.length - 1]` into `candidates[0]` and remove `candidates[candidates.length - 1]`
5. and then will do this operation `randomNumbersCount` times.

**Second iteration**

1. Our candidates array is now `[10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
2. Generate random number let's say `0` again. Wow we generated similar random number, but so what?
3. we alreay have `0` in our results, but `candidates[0]` is not a `0` anymore `candidates[0]` is `10` right now
4. so we pick `candidates[0]` that is `10` and will store it and remove it from candidates. Put `candidates[candidates.length - 1]` (`9`) into `candidates[0]` and remove `candidates[candidates.length - 1]`
5. our result is [0, 10] right now

**Third iteration**

1. Our `candidates` is now `[9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
2. Generate random number let's say `0`
3. we are not worring anymore because we know that `candidates[0]` is `9`
4. add `candidates[0]` (witch is `9`) we are saving to results, and remove it from `candidates`
5. our result is `[0,10,9]`, `candidates` is `[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

**And so on**

BTW implementation is much shorter than explanation:

```js
function renerateRandomNumbers(maxNumber, randomNumbersCount) {
  
  var candidates = [...Array(maxNumber).keys()];
  
  return Array(randomNumbersCount).fill()
    .map(() => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * candidates.length)
      const n = candidates[randomIndex]
      candidates[randomIndex] = candidates[candidates.length - 1]
      candidates.length = candidates.length - 1
      return n
    })
    .sort((a, b) => a - b) // sort if needed
}

console.log (renerateRandomNumbers(10, 5))
```

Comment: I can't help but think the use of `candidates.splice(randomIndex, 1)` is very inefficient for large data sets since splice has to re-index the array - worst case scenario, it's `O(n)`, making this algorithm `O(n*m)` which could potentially be > `O(n^2)`. You could do the same thing in `O(n)` by creating a map of "used" values and doing an index lookup on that map, which is `O(1)`

Comment: The problem with using a "used" map, however, is that whenever the random is a duplicate, you have to regenerate the random number, which.. technically could be an infinite number of times. Not sure how to measure the time complexity of that solution in comparison to yours.

Comment: Your latest edit is much better with the removal of `.slice()`. The only thing to consider now is that `.fill()` and `.map()` are not free; they will each iterate over the array one time. Total number of iterations will be 3n for `[...Array(maxNumber).keys()]`, m for `Array(randomNumbersCount)` + m for `.fill()` + m for `.map()`. So total # of iterations would be `3n + 3m`. In terms of space complexity, you will be creating 4 arrays throughout the course of this algorithm. 2 for `[...Array(maxNumber).keys()]`, 1 for `Array(randomNumbersCount)` and 1 for `.map()`

Comment: Just realized that we both were not inclusive of the maxNumber itself. Should be `Array(maxNumber +1)`

Comment: You can remove the splice by just using the `i` parameter of map with `candidates.length - i` and make the solution almost 2x faster

Answer (score 1):

The solution from mhodges is reasonably efficient, but only when the sought count is fairly close to the max number.  If your count is significantly smaller, this can be a problem, as the solution is `O(m + n)` where `m` is the maximum and `n` is the desired count.  It's also `O(m)` in space.  If `m` is large, this could be a problem.

A variant would make this approximately `O(n)` in time and space, by doing the same thing, but stopping the shuffle when when we've reached `count` items and by not pre-filling the array but instead defaulting to its indices.

```js
function venerateRandomNumbers(max, count) {
  // todo: error if count > max
  const arr = new Array(max + 1)
  for (let i = max; i > max - count; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    const temp = arr[j] || j
    arr[j] = arr[i] || i
    arr[i] = temp
  }
  return arr.slice(-count)
}

console.log(venerateRandomNumbers(1000000, 10))
```

You can see performance comparisons on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@CrossEye/DullTestyClients)

Comment: Very clever. Took me a good while to figure out exactly what this is doing (might want to add some comments), but the performance is excellent.

Comment: Interesting.  The only part that feels a bit over-clever to me is the fact that it depends upon the fact that the values are non-zero.  More explicit might be `temp = arr[j] == undefined ? j : arr[j]`, and similarly for `i`.

Comment: Leveraging sparse arrays is not exactly something that people do every day. It wasn't immediately obvious to me why you would look at `arr[j]` to determine `arr[i]`, and why you have to use `arr[i] || i` to determine `arr[j]`

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of sparse arrays, but they do seem like the appropriate structure here.  The only real alternative I see is an object or Map doing the same job.  It might be more performant, but the code would likely be nastier.