# Can't figure out why my math.random is returning the incorrect values whilst in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 25 slots where I need the first 5 to be numbers from 1-15, next 5 to be 16-30 and so on.

I've done a for loop and a switch case to achieve this but it's returning the wrong values. Outside of the forloop it returns the correct numbers.

```
var num = [];
var col = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4];
var card = [];

    // Filling the num array
function fill(number) {
    for(let i = 1; i < number+1; i++) {
        num.push([i]);
    } // Fills the array from 1 to 'number' and will have no duplicates
}

fill(76);

function fillCard() {
for(let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    switch (col[i]) {
        case 0:
            getRandom(0,15);
            break;
        case 1:
            getRandom(16,30);
            break;
        case 2:
            getRandom(31,45);
            break;
        case 3:
            getRandom(46,60);
            break;
        case 4:
            getRandom(61,75);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
}

function getRandom(min,max) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
    card.push(num[x]);
    num.splice(x,1);
}
```

Comment: One reason that this doesn't work as you would like is that when you `splice` your `num` array, you remove the element at the nth index, which means your array is shorter.  If next time you try to get the 15th element, it won't exist.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Follow-up comments have made it clear that this is an attempt to include random numbers without repeats in each section.

This might be my approach:

```js
function randoms(max, count) {
  // todo: error if count > max
  const arr = new Array(max + 1)
  for (let i = max; i > max - count; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    const temp = arr[j] || j
    arr[j] = arr[i] || i
    arr[i] = temp
  }
  return arr.slice(-count)
}

const ranges = [ [1, 15], [16, 30], [31, 45], [46, 60], [61, 75] ]

const makeCard = (ranges, count) => ranges.map(
  ([min, max]) => randoms(max - min + 1, count).map(n => n + min)
).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])

console.log(makeCard(ranges, 5))
```

`randoms` is a version of the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle which stops after shuffling a fixed number of values. (I took this from an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53157638/1243641) of mine.) . Each call to this chooses five distinct number in the `0 - (max - min)` range, to which we then add `min` in the internal `map` call.

The outer `map` call in `makeCard` calls the random function for each range, which would yield a result such as:

```
[
  [15, 10, 14, 12, 5],
  [17, 30, 29, 20, 16],
  [35, 34, 31, 46, 37],
  [53, 58, 46, 54, 60],
  [70, 65, 75, 74, 62]
]
```

We then call `reduce` on the result passing a function that simply concatenates its two arguments to turn this into a single list.  At some point we'll be able to use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) instead.

One advantage of this approach is that you can easily change the list of ranges, so they don't all have to have equal lengths.  And if you wanted different counts for the ranges, you could move the `count` variable inside the ranges as well (e.g. `[ [5, 16, 30], [7, 31, 50] ]` for "choose 5 distinct number between 16 and 60 and 7 distinct numbers between 31 and 50."  This would involve only a trivial change to the code.

---

(old answer)

## Simple Change

A minimal change to your code that should do what you want is simply to push the value you chose directly onto the array.  (I don't know what `num` is supposed to be here.) This version does that:

```js
var col = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4];
var card = [];

function fillCard() {
for(let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    switch (col[i]) {
        case 0:
            getRandom(0,15);
            break;
        case 1:
            getRandom(16,30);
            break;
        case 2:
            getRandom(31,45);
            break;
        case 3:
            getRandom(46,60);
            break;
        case 4:
            getRandom(61,75);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
}

function getRandom(min,max) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
    card.push(x)
}

fillCard()

console.log(card)
```

## More Advanced

But if you're interested in more advanced techniques for this, you could simply write:

```js
const card = [...new Array(25)].map(
  (_, i) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + (15 * Math.floor(i / 5)) + 1
)

console.log(card)
```

### Explanation

This second version starts `[...new Array(25)]`.  The `new Array(25)` part creates an array that has no actual elements but an artificial length of 25.  Wrapping that with the braces (`[ ]`) and the spread operator (`...`) turns that into an array with 25 actual values, all of which happen to be `undefined`.

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, ... undefined]
```

Now we can `map` over that array, which is the process of applying a function to each value to create a brand new array.  The function we pass to map is

```
(_, i) => Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + (15 * Math.floor(i / 5)) + 1,
```

It takes two parameters, but since we will ignore the first one, we give it the throw-away name of `_`.  There is no magic in that name, but it is a common signal to the reader that this parameter is unimportant.  We use the second parameter, though.  `i` is the index in the array that we're looking at.

The rest is fairly straightforward math.  The `5` represents the number of elements in each group.  The `15`'s represent the size of the random range.  If we wanted, we could write a function that accepted these two values as parameters and returned your array.

Comment: I like that advanced solution a lot and a very good explanation to your code. But I didn't know about a common signal for a throw-away variable name like `_`, especially in JavaScript, whereas there's a framework called underscore using obviously `_` for itself. This convention comes probably from another language?

Comment: It's a convention used in a number of languages when doing pattern matching.  People bringing functional programming techniques from other languages to JS have adopted it as well.  It's only somewhat useful as it can only be used for one parameter at a time, and, as you note, it can conflict with the use of `_` for the Underscore and lodash libraries.

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this is I'm getting repeating numbers, I need the values added into the card array to be unique which is why I used num so I could splice a value once it's been used

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, and it would then require a somewhat different technique.  Perhaps a `shuffle` function would be useful.

Comment: @User2019: Updated with an additional answer that avoids repeats.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks, appreciate you taking the time to explain this for me also

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things that are going wrong - you're looping based on a value that you're changing, but each time you set `i` to a value that will potentially exceed your loop length.

Think through the logic, and tell me if this is accurate:

```
Task: create an array of 25 numbers, each lot of five to be in a different range. The first five between 0 and 15, the next five between 16 and 30, the next five between 31 and 45, the next 46 to 60, and final five between 61 and 75.

* Create an array to define the 'steps'. Based on those steps, we switch our min and max for these array values.

* Create an array to store each of the random numbers.

* While we have a valid length of 'steps' array, use the first to define the current range.

* Use a switch statement to determine the min/max of the current random member.

* remove the first member of the 'steps' array.
```

If these are similar to the steps you're thinking, then you may be overthinking the problem. Instead, simply do exactly those things: use a `while` loop, checking that `col.length` is still greater than zero, and based on `col[0]`, switch.

Here's how it might look:

```js
var col = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4];
var card = [];

function fillCard() {
while(col.length > 0) {
    switch (col[0]) {
        case 0:
            getRandom(0,15);
            break;
        case 1:
            getRandom(16,30);
            break;
        case 2:
            getRandom(31,45);
            break;
        case 3:
            getRandom(46,60);
            break;
        case 4:
            getRandom(61,75);
            break;
        default:
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
}

function getRandom(min,max) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) ) +min;
    card.push(x);
    col.shift();
}

fillCard();
console.log(card)
```

EDIT: The above works fine, for the original spec we were given. If, however, you need to generate UNIQUE random numbers within that range, a different process is required:

1. Create an array of every possible value within the range.
2. Randomly select one of the possible values within that range.
3. Remove the selected value, thus rendering it unique.

Here's how that might code out:

```js
let col = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
  possibles = [],
  card = [];

function fillCard() {
  /**
   * First, create an array of possible values. This will be a nested
   *   array, each sub-array containing fifteen unique sequential
   *   values within our given range.
   */
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    let possibleSubArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j <= 15; j++) {
      possibleSubArray.push(i * 15 + j);
    }
    possibles.push(possibleSubArray);
  }
  
  // Let's see that list of possibles.
  //  console.log(possibles);
  
  // Now, we use col to identify which of the sub-arrays we want to
  //  get our unique value from.
  for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    // getRandom no longer takes a min/max. Now it takes the index
    //  to the given sub-array.
    getRandom(col[i]);
  }

  // This creates a random number based on the length of the subarray
  //  length, then pushes the value at that index onto our 'card'
  //  array. At that point, it removes that number from our 'possibles'
  //  array, thus rendering it unique.
  function getRandom(possiblesSubArrayIndex) {
    let min = 0, max = possibles[possiblesSubArrayIndex].length;
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    // push that random number onto our 'card'
    card.push(possibles[possiblesSubArrayIndex][x]);
    // and remove it from the possible numbers.
    possibles[possiblesSubArrayIndex].splice(x, 1);
  }
}

  fillCard();
  console.log(card);
  // If you want to see what we DIDN'T use for uniques...
//  console.log(possibles);
```

Comment: Definitely on the right track, however I need it to not repeat the same number which is why I used num[x] so once a number is used I am able to splice it so it can't be used again, can you figure out how I'd do this?

Comment: I don't follow your comment about the `i`'s.  The different `i` values are in different scopes (separate functions.)  And they are not altered outside the loop, right?

Comment: This would be quite a bit easier with an actual spec. To do what you're looking for, you'd likely want to do things quite a bit different. It is do-able, but is there more to the spec than "generate five DIFFERENT random numbers between 0 and 15, then between 16 and 30, then..."?

Comment: @User2019, added a second code sample above, which generates UNIQUE values within each range. A little more involved, as I'd said.

Comment: @Snowmonkey thanks a lot for taking the time to help, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will work for you.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()* max + 1 , min)
```

Comment: What does that accomplish?

Comment: I was thinking he might getting problem with Math.random() method. as he explained he was not getting correct random number. this code snippet will solve that problem. if that is the exact issue.

Comment: The issue is, the OP didn't give all the spec, and at a guess is having us write his/her homework for him/her. Random unique numbers, etc.